# Combine datasets in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, lookup

I have a question regarding joining two datasets together.
I now have data that looks like this: (example)

```
| dummy    | ID    | current year|
| -------- | -------------- |-------   |
| 0        | 1           |1621
| 0        | 1           |1622
| 0        | 1           |1623
| 1        | 1           |1624
| 0        | 2           |1623
| 0        | 2           |1624
| 0        | 2           |1625
| 0        | 2           |1626
| 0        | 2           |1627
| 1        | 2           |1628
```

I have another huge dataset containing all sorts of information about every transaction, for example:

```
| Gender    | ID    | Price| 
| -------- | -------------- |-------   |
| 1        | 1           |16
| 0        | 2           |12
| 0        | 3           |13
| 1        | 4           |22
| 0        | 5           |23
| 0        | 6           |38
| 1        | 7           |10
| 0        | 8           |16
| 0        | 9           |17
| 1        | 10           |8.
```

I now want to add a column to the first dataframe, which states the gender for every row. I guess this could be done by looking at the ID. Note that the first dataset has multiple rows per ID, and is thus much longer. I have no idea how to do this so any help would be appreciated, let me know if anything is still unclear :)
Like this:

| dummy | ID | current year | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1621 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1622 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1623 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1624 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | 1623 | 0 |
| 0 | 2 | 1624 | 0 |
| 0 | 2 | 1625 | 0 |
| 0 | 2 | 1626 | 0 |
| 0 | 2 | 1627 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1628 | 0 |

Comment: See `merge` if you're using base R, or `left_join` if you're using `dplyr`.

Comment: Use `merge(df1, df2, by = 'ID')`.